# PHPMailer: Am I connected to external SMPT or not?

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I got the following piece of log which was outputted by PHPMailer:

```
2020-02-03 13:39:00 Connection: opening to some-external.smtp.host:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-02-03 13:39:00 Connection: opened
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-my-own.domain.com ESMTP Exim 4.92 #2 Mon, 03 Feb 2020 13:39:00 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-02-03 13:39:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO url-at-my-own.domain.com
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-url-at-my-own.domain.com Hello url-at-my-own.domain.com [31.186.175.24]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-02-03 13:39:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@domain.com>
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2020-02-03 13:39:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<recipient@hotmail.com>
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 550-(test.admin.mijnvolksuniversiteit.nl) [31.186.175.24]:50402 is not550 permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 550-(url-at-my-own.domain.com) [31.186.175.24]:50402 is not550 permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
2020-02-03 13:39:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-02-03 13:39:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 url-at-my-own.domain.com closing connection
2020-02-03 13:39:00 Connection: closed
```

Now, the problem is 'obvious', the server requests that I authenticate myself, however that is not the issue at hand here. What is important is knowing wether or not I am really connected to 'some-external.smtp.host' or something on 'my-own.domain.com'.

I am dealing with an external party that manages 'some-external.smtp.host' that claims I shouldn't need to authenticate because 'my-own.domain.com' server IP is white listed.

They specifically claim that I seem to be connected to a local SMTP server because of this pieces in line 3 'SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-my-own.domain.com ESMTP Exim' containing my own domain name and not theirs.

I believe, because line 1 specifically states a connection is made to 'some-external.smtp.host' and line 2 states that the connection was opened successfully, that the 220 message in line 3 is the external host (aka SERVER) is addressing local server (aka CLIENT) by its name.

Since I have no administratorial access to the server on my end I am looking for ways to find out whom is right here. I really hope to rule out that I am not connected to something local and that it really is their server stonewalling me.

The code used to iniate the PHPMailer is as follows:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
                    try {
                        //Server settings
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
                        $mail->isSMTP();
                        $mail->Host       = $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_host'];
                        if($this->vu['setting_mailrelay_username'] != '' && $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_password'] != '') {
                            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                            $mail->Username   = $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_username'];
                            $mail->Password   = $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_password'];
                        }
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_security'];
                        if($this->vu['setting_mailrelay_security'] == '') {
                            $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
                        }
                        $mail->Port       = $this->vu['setting_mailrelay_port'];

                        //Recipients
                        $mail->setFrom($this->vu['email'], $this->vu['name']);
                        $mail->addAddress($email_to, trim($person['last_name']));
                        $mail->addReplyTo($this->vu['email'], $this->vu['name']);

                        // Content
                        $mail->isHTML(true);
                        $mail->Subject = $subject;
                        $mail->Body    = $mailBody;
                        $mail->AltBody = $message_plain;

                        $mail->send();
                        echo 'Message has been sent';
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
                    }
```

The SMTPAuth in my case is false, with username and password being emtpy because of the external party insisting that I do not need to authenticate.

The SMTPSecure is empty and SMTPAutoTLS is false because the external party insists that encryption should be off.

**Update:**
If I do enable TLS the log is as follows:

```
2020-02-04 13:08:11 Connection: opening to some-external.smtp.host:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-02-04 13:08:11 Connection: opened
2020-02-04 13:08:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-my-own.domain.com ESMTP Exim 4.92 #2 Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:08:11 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-02-04 13:08:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO url-at-my-own.domain.com
2020-02-04 13:08:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-my-own.domain.com Hello url-at-my-own.domain.com [31.186.175.24]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-02-04 13:08:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-02-04 13:08:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2020-02-04 13:08:11 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`my-own.domain.com' did not match expected CN=`some-external.smtp.host' [/home/tstvubo/public_html/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 429]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-02-04 13:08:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-02-04 13:08:12
2020-02-04 13:08:12
2020-02-04 13:08:12 Connection: closed
```

This causes the server to complain about certificates on either side not matching, ok so... if I adjust the calling PHP code to apply:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = ['ssl' => [
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
];
```

The result becomes as follows:

```
2020-02-04 13:12:51 Connection: opening to some-external.smtp.host:25, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2020-02-04 13:12:51 Connection: opened
2020-02-04 13:12:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-my-own.domain.com ESMTP Exim 4.92 #2 Tue, 04 Feb 2020 13:12:51 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2020-02-04 13:12:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO url-at-my-own.domain.com
2020-02-04 13:12:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-my-own.domain.com Hello url-at-my-own.domain.com [31.186.175.24]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2020-02-04 13:12:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-02-04 13:12:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2020-02-04 13:12:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO url-at-my-own.domain.com
2020-02-04 13:12:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-my-own.domain.com Hello url-at-my-own.domain.com [31.186.175.24]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
2020-02-04 13:12:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<info@domain.com>
2020-02-04 13:12:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
2020-02-04 13:12:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<recipient@hotmail.com>
2020-02-04 13:12:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 550-(url-at-my-own.domain.com) [31.186.175.24]:36810 is not550 permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
2020-02-04 13:12:52 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. 550-(url-at-my-own.domain.com) [31.186.175.24]:36810 is not550 permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
2020-02-04 13:12:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-02-04 13:12:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 my-own.domain.com closing connection
2020-02-04 13:12:52 Connection: closed
```

And now it asks for authentication, yet again.

This leads to the following conclusions:

- I am most definitely connected to the external SMTP server.
- Despite what the external party claims, a simple IP white list isn't going to cut it.
- I need either some authentication credentials or a proper certificate to communicate with.

Verdict?

Comment: Whats in `$this->vu['setting_mailrelay_host']`?
Anyways, if they want you to omit encryption I would omit their service.

Comment: That value holds the 'some-external.smtp.host'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a **really, really good idea to actually read the error message**, especially this bit:

> `Peer certificate CN='my-own.domain.com' did not match expected CN='some-external.smtp.host'`

That means that while you may be asking to connect to `some-external.smtp.host` (because that's what you put in the `Host` property), you are actually connected to `my-own.domain.com`.

This is typically due to firewall rules redirecting SMTP traffic – it also means that TLS is doing *exactly* what it was designed to do and alerting you that your traffic is effectively subject to a man-in-the-middle attack (by your own firewall), so disabling certificate verification is, as usual, a bad idea. This exact problem is covered in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#firewall-redirection).

So what they say is correct; it's not them doing this – it's *your* mail server that's asking for authentication, not theirs.

Comment: Well darn, I even called the host of the 'my-own.domain.com' server, explained the situation to them and they told me that as long as I had a hostname that wasn't on their domain there would be no way the SMTP server on 'my-own.domain.com' wasn't kicking in. But I guess that can't be true then.

Comment: So, TLS deffo is going to have to be turned on of course. So that means I gotta slug it out with the opposing parties to arrange for matching certificates?

Comment: The opposing party isn't doing anything wrong, and they're not going to be able to get a cert for someone else's domain. You need to ask your hosting provider to stop intercepting your SMTP traffic, as it's most likely them that's doing it.

Comment: Hmm ok, what is weird is. It was working perfectly fine when I target mailtrap.io SMTP (with TLS & credentials) for example. But not when I target say smtp.office365.com (with TLS & credentials), then I keep seeing 'my-own.domain.com' in de 220 lines.

Comment: It's possible they could be selective in the redirection. You may be able to investigate further using `curl` and `openssl s_client`.

Comment: $ openssl s_client -connect some-external.smtp.host:25 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = TX, L = Houston, O = "cPanel, Inc.", CN = "cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority"
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, `CN = my-own.domain.com`
verify return:1

Redirection right? :(

Comment: Most likely - best thing is to try it from some other location that's not behind your firewall and compare the two.

Comment: Heavens you were dead on. That comment in the troubleshoot about cPanel's WHM smtp security settings were what is blocking us, we disabled it and it instantly worked. Gah.